# node.js server not always clearing data from previous run

Tags: node.js, reset

I'm brand new to node.js (or javascript in general) and not sure what's going on here. Sometimes when I run my node.js server, right when it starts up it begins printing data from the last time it ran. Is there something that could be keeping everything from resetting on a new run? I have arduino XBee nodes connecting to this server. Here's my node.js code:

```
var SerialPort = require("serialport");
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
var ON_DEATH = require('death');

// Set up serial port 
var portName = process.argv[2],
portConfig = {
    baudRate: 9600,
    parser: SerialPort.parsers.readline("\n")
};
var sp = new SerialPort(portName, portConfig); // got rid of deprecation issue with sp4

// Respond with file when a GET request is made to the homepage: app.METHOD(PATH, HANDLER) '/'=homepage
app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.sendfile('index.html');
});             

// Listen on the connection event for incoming sockets, and log it to the console.
io.on('connection', function(socket){
    console.log('a user connected');
    socket.on('disconnect', function(){
    });
    socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
        io.emit('chat message', msg);
        sp.write(msg + "\n");
    });
});

// Make the http server listen on port 3000
http.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log('listening on *:3000');
});

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

sp.on("open", function (err) {
    if (err) 
        return console.log('Error opening port: ', err.message);
    console.log('open');

    // INFO VARIABLES
    //var nodeCount = 0;
    var pendingNodes = [];
    var connectedNodes = [];
    var buffer0;
    var nodeInfo;   

    // Cleanup when termination signals are sent to process
    ON_DEATH(function(signal, err) {
        var death_msg = "Q";
        sp.write(death_msg);
        sp.close();     
        // zero out all variables
        pendingNodes = [];
        connectedNodes = [];
        buffer0 = [];
        nodeInfo = [];

        console.log("\n\nSending reset signal to nodes.\n\n")
        sp.flush(function(err,results){});
        process.exit();
    })

    // listen for data, grab time, delimit
    sp.on('data', function(data) {
    var time = new Date();
    buffer0 = data.split('\n'); // array of data till newline
    // Split again into either "#ID" into [#ID] (if new broadcast), or "#ID Data" into [#ID, Data] (preconnected node)
    nodeInfo = buffer0[0].split('   ');
    //console.log("     nodeInfo: " + nodeInfo);

    // DEBUGGING PRINT -- DELETE LATER
    //console.log("     pendingNodes: " + pendingNodes + "     connectedNodes: " + connectedNodes);


////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    // Receiving ID or [ID, Data] -- Testing all possible cases

    // if first char 
    if (nodeInfo[0][0] == "#") { // could check up here for && no temp data too 

        // Brand new node (ID not in pendingNodes or connectedNodes)
        if ((pendingNodes.indexOf(nodeInfo[0]) == -1) && (connectedNodes.indexOf(nodeInfo[0]) == -1)) {
            console.log("Brand new node: " + nodeInfo[0])
            pendingNodes.push(nodeInfo[0]);

        }


        // Pending node (ID in pendingNodes, but not in connectedNodes)
        else if ((pendingNodes.indexOf(nodeInfo[0]) != -1) && ((connectedNodes.indexOf(nodeInfo[0]) == -1))) {
            console.log("  Pending node: " + nodeInfo[0])

            // send back ID to confirm handshake
            sp.write(nodeInfo[0]);
            // Remove from pendingNodes
            var index = pendingNodes.indexOf(nodeInfo[0]);
            if (index > -1) {
                pendingNodes.splice(index, 1);
            }
            // Add to connectedNodes
            //var 
            connectedNodes.push(nodeInfo[0]);


        }
        // Connected node (ID in connectedNodes, but not in pendingNodes)
        else if  ((pendingNodes.indexOf(nodeInfo[0]) == -1) && (connectedNodes.indexOf(nodeInfo[0]) != -1)) {
            console.log("    Connected node: " + nodeInfo[0] + "   " + nodeInfo[1]);

            // Disconnect nodes with undefined temperatures to force restart
            if (typeof nodeInfo[1] == 'undefined') {
                console.log("Undefined data for node: " + nodeInfo[0] + ". Dropping connection to this node.");
                var index = connectedNodes.indexOf(nodeInfo[0]);
                if (index > -1) {
                    connectedNodes.splice(index, 1);
                }

            }

            //var t = time.getTime();

            // FIRST: fix bug -- sometimes temp showing as undefined            
            // Then:
            // Update data properly
            // Average data
            // add 3rd element to nodes for time stamp, check that all timestamps are recent periodically
            // Detect drop-offs and remove nodes

        }
        // Error (ID in both pendingNodes and connectedNodes [should not happen])
        else {
            console.log("Error: node exists in both pending and connected.")

        }


    }
    else if (nodeInfo[0][0] != "#") {
        // FOR DEBUGGING PURPOSES, DELETE LATER
        console.log("Error 2: incoming data does not start with '#'.")
    }



    /* // placeholders for functionality to add
    var CalcAverage = function() {
        console.log("CalcAverage: * every 1 second(s) *");
    }
    setInterval(function(){ CalcAverage() },2000);  


    var CheckNodes = function() {
        console.log("CheckNodes: * every 6 second(s) *");
    }
    setInterval(function(){ CheckNodes() },6000);
    */



    }); // end data
}); // end open
```

And here's an example of old node data showing up somehow:

[image]

Comment: Please edit the post to [only contain the minimal code you need](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to reproduce your problem; it's hard to go through 150 lines of code to find a problem unless you know exactly what the problem is...

Comment: Last 3 times I tried doing that and was told I didn't post enough code.. it's hard for me to tell what's relevant when I don't have a clue what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Some possibilities:

Old (or new data that you didn't know it sent) data from clients has been buffered somehow on the serial port, or socket.io auto-reconnects on the client browsers and starts sending data even though you didn't interact with the client browser web page.

Comment: Is there a way to clear all buffered data when the server starts? I tried doing `sp.flush()`, but I don't think that worked.

Comment: I think try to determine if its related to Node at all. If it is buffered serial data, you may be able to check somehow with a different serial client, and if it is then it has nothing to do with Node, so you might look for some kind of Linux utility or script to do it. You may want to turn off either the browser stuff or serial port to test one at a time (and also test one client at a time).

Comment: I think when I do `buffer = data.split('\n');`, data has old serial port data. Is there a javascript command to clear the serial buffer first before looking at data?

Comment: If you restarted your server process it is impossible for data from the previous run to be in there.